# Adding Web Pages to JabRef

Tags: lyx, jabref

I want to add webpage article (from New York Times) in my research paper. How can I add it to my bibigraphie . I can add using JabRef (research Article, Book, Booklet, .. ). but how can I add -automatically- webpage.

Should I use this code, or is there any other faster way to do that ?

```
@WEB{NYTimes,
  key = {NY-Immigration},
  link = {http://www.nytimes.com/2014/02/07/us/politics/boehner-doubts-immigration-overhaul-will-pass-this-year.html?_r=0},
  owner = {user3378649},
  timestamp = {2014.02.06},
  title = {Boehner Doubts Immigration Bill Will Pass in 2014},
  year = {2014}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the "Online" type in JabRef:

[image]

Which yields the following:

```
@ONLINE{CFD2011,
  author = {Cfd-online},
  title = {Dimensionless wall distance (y plus)},
  year = {2011},
  url = {http://www.cfd-online.com/Wiki/Dimensionless_wall_distance_%28y_plus%29},
  note = {[Online; Stand 19. Dezember 2012]},
  owner = {LaRiFaRi},
  timestamp = {2012.12.19}
}
```

and than print it (if you want as a separated section):

```
\printbibliography[
    heading=bibliography,
    title=Bibliography,
    nottype=online
]
\printbibliography[
    heading=subbibliography,
    title=Online sources,
    type=online
]
```

I don't know, if this is relevant, but I run this with the package:

```
\usepackage[%
    ,backend=biber
]{biblatex}
```

Comment: Can I use JabRef ? or should I insert this code in the .bib library ?

Comment: I am using JabRef and would recommend it to everybody. I just copied the entry above from one of my JabRef-files.

Comment: @user3378649 in case you are missing the possibility to add `online`-resources in JabRef, you may want to toggle "Settings-Advanced-BibLaTeX-Mode" to "on".

Comment: I turned BibLaTeX-Mode to on, but when I tried to add a new reference, I couldn't find "WEB". Or should I add it using "Manual" , then customize the above-mentioned code.

Comment: You should add "Online". Can't you see this in your program? I tested 2.9.2 and 2.10. on Windows for you.

Comment: I didn't restart the app. Note for anyone going through this prob. you should restart the app ;)

Comment: You can do what @LaRiFaRi said, under `File`->`Switch to BibTeX mode`.